Fluent-bit bitnami helm chart - kubernetes filter does not work
I am trying to run fluent-bit using bitnami helm chart and I want to use kubernetes filter. It does collect the logs but the kubernetes filter does not add any information(pod id, pod name etc). When I am using official fluent-bit helm with similar config it works fine.
There are no errors in fluentbit pods logs.
I am deploying it using:
helm upgrade fluentbit oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/fluent-bit --install --wait --version '2.1.1' --namespace 'default' --set daemonset.enabled=$true -f fluent-bit-config.yaml
where fluent-bit-config.yaml is:
config:
  inputs: |
    [INPUT]
        Name    tail
        Tag     kube.*
        Path    /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri

  filters: |
    [FILTER]
        Name             kubernetes
        Match            kube.*

  outputs: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name es
        Match kube.*
        Host gvpelastic-elasticsearch-master.default.svc.cluster.local
        Logstash_Format On
        Retry_Limit False
        Trace_Error On
        Replace_Dots On

I have tried to turn off some security settings of the helm chart, none of that I have tried helps.
Logs for fluent-bit chart:
Logs for fluent-bit chart
Logs for bitnami chart:
Logs for bitnami chart

You should delete the Parser docker in your [INPUT] section.
fluentbit config are under config key, so your fluent-bit-config.yaml should be:
config:
  inputs: |
    [INPUT]
        Name    tail
        Tag     kube.*
        Path    /var/log/containers/*.log
        multiline.parser docker, cri

  filters: |
    [FILTER]
        Name             kubernetes
        Match            kube.*

  outputs: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name es
        Match kube.*
        Host elasticsearch-master.default.svc.cluster.local
        Logstash_Format On
        Retry_Limit False
        Trace_Error On
        Replace_Dots On


Thank you for your answer, unfortunately I have the keyword "config" just did not copy that and I have already tried without Parser docker, also does not work.
Have tried again to make sure. Same result, for bitnami helm chart does not work.
For now I decided to use https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/fluent/fluent-bit instead of https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/fluent-bit.

Maybe try debug logging if you still want to use bitnami fluentbit. The k8s filter is just extracting information from the Tag, which is set by the tail input to the full file path monitored by the tail plugin. See https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/kubernetes#workflow-of-tail--kubernetes-filter for more details.
